# Yahoo smtp is not sending mails but same code is working fine for gmail.Need help.working on local server

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

Sample code of yahoo SMTP mailer

This code is working properly for Gmail but for yahoo its showing

```
SMTP -> ERROR: Failed           to connect to server: (0) 
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Message has been sent.......

with port no 465
SMTP -> ERROR: MAIL not accepted from server: 501 Syntax error in arguments 

The following From address failed: root@localhost Message has been sent.......


<?php
include('class.phpmailer.php');
include('class.smtp.php');
try {
$mail = new PHPMailer();  
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com"; //smtp host
$mail->Port = 25; //port no.
$mail->Username = "eg@yahoo.com"; //account 
$mail->Password = "pass"; //password
$fromname = "name";
$email="someone@gmail.com";
$abcd="-------------";
$To = trim($email,"\r\n");
  $tContent   = '';

  $tContent .="<table width='550px' colspan='2' cellpadding='4'>
        <tr><td align='center'><img src='imgpath' width='100' height='100'></td></tr>
        <tr><td height='20'>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <table cellspacing='1' cellpadding='1' width='100%' height='100%'>
            <tr><td align='center'><h2>YOUR TEXT<h2></td></tr/>
            <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr><td align='center'>Name: ".trim($abcd,"\r\n")."</td></tr>
            <tr><td align='center'>ABCD TEXT: ".$abcd."</td></tr>
            <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>                
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
        </table>";

  $mail->FromName = $fromname;        
  $mail->Subject = "Your Details."; 
  $mail->Body = $tContent;
  $mail->AddAddress($To); 
  //$mail->set('X-Priority', '1'); //Priority 1 = High, 3 = Normal, 5 = low
  $mail->Send();
    echo 'Message has been sent.......';
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
echo $e->errorMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: For yahoo you might need yahoo plus account.

Comment: Please tell me which are the other mail providers like gmail from which I can send promotionals emails free.

Answer (score 0):

For yahoo you might need yahoo plus account. see the requirements below for yahoo smtp :

```
Yahoo! Mail Outgoing Mail (SMTP) Server: smtp.mail.yahoo.com
Use Authentication: Yes
Port: 25 or 587    
Yahoo! Mail Incoming Mail (POP3) Server: Only available in Yahoo! Mail Plus
Account Name: Your full email address or your Yahoo! ID
Email Address: Your email address
Password: Your Yahoo! ID password
```

Note 1: If your Internet Service Provider (ISP) blocks Port 25, you will have to use an alternate SMTP Port number such as 587.

Note 2: AT&T customers use smtp.att.yahoo.com and Port 465 with SSL

Note 3: If you are using Yahoo! Small Business Email, More details at [Here](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/smallbusiness/bizmail/pop/pop-33.html).

Other providers you can use Outlook/Hotmail, AOL Outgoing Mail

Comment: can I do the same thing for Outlook/Hotmail, AOL Outgoing Mail like as gmail. or I need to have any special account like yahoo plus.

Comment: i haven't try but it wont need any special account for AOL and outlook.

Comment: May be ....Just now i got a mail in my hotmail account We noticed some unusual activity in your Outlook.com account. To help protect you, we've temporarily blocked your account.
Why are you seeing this?
Someone may have used your account to send out a lot of junk emails or something else that violates our Terms of Service.

Comment: may be, because you are using your hotmail with code(Remotely). Sometimes gmail also require same kind of permissions. try to find if hotmail also need any special permission.

Comment: $mail = new PHPMailer();  
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
    $mail->Host = "smtp.live.com";
    $mail->Port = 587;

Comment: witl tls its sending but with ssl its not sending

Comment: The mail was sent from my hotmail account to a gmail account but its receiving as spam.The mail was there in my hotmail sent box